# How to write program text in table

Tags: tables, listings, sourcecode

I have to write a table with two columns and in each column I have to place small C code snippets. Using the `\code{}` in each column seems to be very tedious because I have to write 
`\code{}` in each line on each box of the table.

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Possible transformations}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
{\small
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}\hline\hline
code1           & code2 \\\hline
\code{float PI = 3.14;} & \code{constexpr double PI = 3.14;} \\\hline
\code{if(A > B) A = B } & \code{void F(T\& A, const T\& B)}\\
                & \code{\{if (A>B) A=B; \} } \\\hline
\end{minipage}
\label{tab:general-transformation}
\end{table}
```

Also I want 2-3 lines of code in each box.
How do I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Note that an MWE should include document class, all necessary packages and definitions (where does `\code` come from, for example?) and a `document` environment. In other words, we should be able to copy the whole thing into a new file and compile it. At the same time, it should be minimal, so any packages etc. that doesn't influence the problem, should be left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) and the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu*}{XX}
\tabucline-
\Verb!&_$^#$!
& 
\Verb!___$^#$!
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\begin{Verbatim}
Some lines
of a long
verbatim fragment
\end{Verbatim}
&
\begin{Verbatim}
Some lines
of another long
verbatim fragment
\end{Verbatim}
\\
\tabucline-
\end{tabu*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if your verbatim material doesn't require any special treatment and doesn't include any special characters, you can use the `>{...}` syntax to add `\ttfamily` to the columns and simply say something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\small\ttfamily}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{C{3cm}C{4.5cm}}
\toprule
code1 & code2 \\
\midrule
float PI = 3.14; & constexpr double PI = 3.14; \\
\midrule
if(A > B) A = B  & void F(T\& A, const T\& B) \\
& \{if (A>B) A=B; \} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]